# electron-packager with sqlite3 and webpack

Tags: webpack, sqlite, electron, electron-packager

I'm making a small application that gets/stores data using [sqlite3](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sqlite3).

Everything was fine during development stage. But when I used [electron-packager](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-packager) to pack my application, `sqlite3` doesn't work anymore.

The console display an exception which is : **Cannot find module 'sqlite3'**.
[image: sqlite 3 exception]

This is my renderer configuration:

```
return {
        target: 'electron-renderer',
        mode: argv.production ? 'production' : 'development',
        context: paths.root,
        devtool: !argv.production ? 'source-map' : false,
        entry: {
            'app': path.resolve(paths.app, 'app.js')
        },
        optimization: {
            runtimeChunk: false,
            splitChunks: {
                chunks: 'all',
                cacheGroups: {
                    default: {
                        enforce: true,
                        priority: 1
                    },
                    vendors: {
                        test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
                        priority: 2,
                        name: 'vendors',
                        enforce: true,
                        chunks: 'async'
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        module: {
            rules: require('./rule')(paths, argv).get()
        },
        plugins: require('./plugin')(paths, argv).get(),
        output: {
            path: paths.dist,
            filename: 'app.bundled.js'
        },
        resolve: {
            // Add `.ts` and `.tsx` as a resolvable extension.
            extensions: [".ts", ".tsx", ".js"],
            alias: {
                // summernote: codemirror
                'CodeMirror': 'codemirror',
            }
        },
        watch: !argv.production,
        watchOptions: {
            poll: false
        },
        externals: {
            sqlite3: 'commonjs sqlite3'
        }
    };
```

This is the file belongs to renderer process in which I include `sqlite3`:

```
const typeorm = require('typeorm');
const EntitySchema = typeorm.EntitySchema;
const path = require('path');
const electron = require('electron');
require('sqlite3');

module.exports = (ngModule) => {
    ngModule.service('$db', (toastr) => {

        //#region Properties

        // Instance of database connection
        let dbConnection = null;

        //#endregion

        let out = {

            //#region Methods
                if (dbConnection == null || forceReinitialize) {
                    // Build a absolute path to database.
                    const appPath = electron.remote.app.getAppPath();
                    const dbPath = path.join(appPath, 'assets/db/PersonalCv.db');
                    return typeorm
                        .createConnection({
                            type: "sqlite",
                            database: dbPath,
                            synchronize: false,
                            entities: [
                                new EntitySchema(require('../models/entities/user')),
                                new EntitySchema(require('../models/entities/user-decription')),
                                new EntitySchema(require('../models/entities/skill-category')),
                                new EntitySchema(require('../models/entities/skill')),
                                new EntitySchema(require('../models/entities/personal-skill')),
                                new EntitySchema(require('../models/entities/project')),
                                new EntitySchema(require('../models/entities/project-skill')),
                                new EntitySchema(require('../models/entities/project-responsibility')),
                                new EntitySchema(require('../models/entities/responsibility'))
                            ]
                        })
                        .then((connection) => {
                            dbConnection = connection;
                            return dbConnection;
                        })
                        .catch((error) => {
                            toastr.error(error);
                            throw error;
                        });
                }

                return new Promise(resolve => {
                    resolve(dbConnection);
                });
            },

            /*
            * Get repository by using name (table name)
            * */
            getRepository: (name) => {
                return out
                    .getConnection()
                    .then((connection) => {
                        return connection.getRepository(name);
                    });
            }

            //#endregion
        };

        return out;
    });
};
```

Here is my [repo](https://bitbucket.org/Redplane/ng-electron-structure/src) in case anyone needs further information.

Can anyone help me please ?

Thank you,

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After going through some Q&A of `electron-packager` and `electron-builder`. I found one solution to make `sqlite3` to work with `webpack`.

In `webpack.config.js`, I added :

```
externals: {
    sqlite3: 'commonjs sqlite3'
}
```

Instead of `electron-packager`, I used `electron-builder` to build my application. In `build` configuration, I copied `sqlite3` module to `dist` folder.

Comment: Thanks, the part I was missing in my project was `commonjs`, I had only `sqlite3`, with no success, but after adding `commonjs sqlite3`, sqlite is working

Comment: How do I add it in craco.config ?

Answer (score 1):

sqlite3 is a native module depending on the system architecture.
Electron-packager doesn't do anything special to help you compile native modules.

So you can either use a pure JS SQLite package like https://github.com/kripken/sql.js/

Or try electron-builder : https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-builder which has a "postinstall" script.

See also : https://electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/using-native-node-modules

Comment: I'm using webpack to bundle my source code. What can I do with `electron-builder` to deal with `sqlite3` ?